# How to get multiple selected checkbox item from multiple checkbox list in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

i have minimal reproduce here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uwfsyv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html, there i have 2 array,`checkboxesDataList` and `checkboxesDataList2` i successfully get the checked label from `checkboxesDataList` but that's just for an example.

but what i wanted to get in my project is similar to `checkboxesDataList2` inside here i have object `question` and `checkboxesDataList` don't have that so this function

```
  fetchSelectedItems() {
    this.selectedItemsList = this.checkboxesDataList.filter((value, index) => {
      return value.checked;
    });
  }
```

won't work immediately if i change `this.checkboxesDataList` to `this.checkboxesDataList2` how can i make it work?

Answer (score 0):

do you want to has a function like?

```
getDataChecked()
{
    return this.checkboxesDataList2.question
          .map(x=>x.options.filter(o=>o.checked))
          .reduce((acc, value)=>[...acc,...value])
}
```

Comment: actually i change my code and i have other issue i've posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650005/get-value-from-all-checked-checkbox-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment112555014_63650005