# Get value from all checked checkbox in angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-reactive-forms

i'm creating quiz app using angular and i have code like this

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      lessonCode: "test",
      answer: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }
  
  onChange(email: string, code: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const emailFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.answer;

    if (isChecked) {
      let array = new FormGroup({
        questionCode: new FormControl(email),
        emailCode: new FormArray([
          new FormControl(code)
        ]),
      });
      emailFormArray.push(array);
    } else {
      let index = emailFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == email);
      emailFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
```

[image]

which producing array like this

```
Form values: {
  "lessonCode": "test",
  "answer": [
    {
      "questionCode": "pertanyaan2",
      "emailCode": [
        "option2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "questionCode": "pertanyaan2",
      "emailCode": [
        "option1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

but what i'm actually needed is like this

```
Form values: {
  "lessonCode": "test",
  "answer": [
    {
      "questionCode": "pertanyaan2",
      "emailCode": {
        "option2",
        "option1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

how can i achieve that? any thoughts would be very helpful

i have minimal reproduce here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ca1jin?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: emailCode propery is not valid object in your expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to add `emailCode` as `FormArray` instead of `FormControl`, this way you will be able to check whether the `questionCode` already exists, and if yes, you can append to `emailCode` the option you checked.

The only things to change are on your `onChange` method

First you `array` variable, you need to add `FormArray` instead of `FormControl`

```
let array = new FormGroup({
  questionCode: new FormControl(email),
  emailCode: new FormArray([])
});
```

Then create a `FormControl` for your checked option

```
let codeOption = new FormControl(code)
```

And finally, in your `if` condition, check if the questionCode already exist to just append your formControl to it, or to create a new object.

```
if (isChecked) {
  if (emailFormArray.controls.some(obj => obj.get('questionCode').value == email)){
    (<FormArray>emailFormArray.controls.find(obj => obj.get('questionCode').value == email).get('emailCode')).push(codeOption);
  }else{
    (<FormArray>array.get('emailCode')).push(codeOption)
    emailFormArray.push(array)
  }
}
```

To be more clear I have modified your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4b6qc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to fit with your needs

I have not modified the `else` condition to remove the options on your `FormArray` but you just need to copy the `if` condition to get the index of the `code` element on your `FormArray` of `emailCode`.

Comment: that's exactly what i needed, thanks a lot, so i just need to figure out how to remove unchecked option from the array right?

Comment: Yep, all you need is as before, get the index of the code in your emailCode formarray

Comment: okay i'll try, hope u can help me again i'll post any issue with this if i have any, thanks man

Comment: sorry, you said copy the `if` condition, which `if` condition should i copy?

Comment: I have modified the stackblitz, and now you are able to properly remove the options from your objects

Comment: i actually trying to write code like that, but ur code much much better than i am, really appreciate it man

Comment: @Alexis, it's not necesary that email was a FormArray, a FormControl can store an array too

Answer (score 2):

I suggested another aproach

If we create a formGroup like

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  lessonCode: "test",
  answer: this.fb.array(this.users.map(x=>this.fb.group({
      questionCode:x.code,
      email:[[]]        
  })))
});
```

See that answer is a FormArray of FormGroup, each FormGroup has two FormsControl, questionCode and email, that is still a FormControl (but store an array). You need don't confussed with a FormArray. A FormControl can store an array, an object, an string, a number, etc.. And it's no so strange store an array, e.g. the mat-select multiple store an array too

As always we work with formArrays we declare a getter to manage in the .html

```
  get answers()
  {
    return this.myForm.get('answer') as FormArray
  }
```

Well, the form is a bit complex

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="answer">
    <div *ngFor="let group of answers.controls;let i=index">
        <p>{{users[i].code}}</p>
        <div *ngFor="let user of users[i].email">
            <input #check type="checkbox" 
      [value]="answers.at(i).value.email.indexOf(user.code)>=0"
      (change)="onChange(i,user.code,check.checked)" >{{user.code}}<br>
      </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

See how we use `[value]="answers.at(i).value.email.indexOf(user.code)>=0"` Really it's not necesary if our "email" control is at first empy, but it possible we want in a future use this form to show the result, and our "eamil" can value, e.g. "[option1]"

Another thing to take account is that I use a template reference variable `#check` and send to the function OnChange `check.checked` -so we received in the function a boolean-

Our function OnChange get more simple

```
  onChange(index:number, code: string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const control=this.answers.at(index).get('email')

    if (isChecked && control.value.indexOf(code)<0)
       control.setValue([...control.value,code]
       .sort((a:string,b:string)=>
          this.users[index].email.findIndex(x=>x.code==a)>
          this.users[index].email.findIndex(x=>x.code==b)?1:-1)
       )

    if (!isChecked && control.value.indexOf(code)>=0)
       control.setValue(control.value.filter(x=>x!=code))
  }
```

I like check if exist or not before remove/add the element

See that we need "sort" the response when the check is true -else we received the response, e.g. [option2,option1] -If our requeriments don't required we can remove the sort-

[The stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yghsm2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Following the question it seems that naoval wanted options as formcontrols and not as values, in your case you put each option as values only.

Comment: i'm speechless, it's beyond my knowledge xD really helpfull though if someone found this post and read your solution, i can learn from this,thanks a lot man

Comment: actually i'm not really concern about whether it's a formcontrol or a value, as long as i get the same result, it'll be just fine

Comment: but like i said, maybe someone will find solutions from you two one day they can chooose which one is most suited to their need :)

Comment: @naoval finally what you need is only a json with your option checked ? If yes our two solutions are complex for nothing :/ you can just have an initial json ans had the option if it's checked or not

Comment: yes i just realized that, i actually have other code that maybe simpler than you guys, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649358/how-to-get-multiple-selected-checkbox-item-from-multiple-checkbox-list-in-angular i posted before i get code in this post

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that traverses every answer and returns an object in your desired schema.

Comment: i dont understand, can u explain it?